# How do i split each 8 bits in 24 bits in Python version 3

Tags: python-3.x, list, image-processing, split, pixel

How can i do this in Python 3. For example:

list = ['123456781234567812345678','123456781234567812345678']

into this:
[['12345678','12345678','12345678'],['12345678','12345678','12345678']]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With regexp you could write:

```
import re
alist = ['123456781234567812345678','123456781234567812345678']
reg = re.compile('12345678')
print([reg.findall(elem) for elem in alist])
# [['12345678', '12345678', '12345678'], ['12345678', '12345678', '12345678']]
```